# Does Kendo have an ASP.NET Web API 2 server side wrapper?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo has a server side wrapper for ASP.NET MVC (which is pretty much deprecated by Microsoft now). Do they have one for the new Web API 2 where it provides a REST/JSON service?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean that ASP.NET MVC is "deprecated"?  I think it's far from deprecated.  In addition, you're talking about two separate things.  The Web API is simply what would provide the data to your Kendo controls.  You could use the server side wrappers or just the client side code.

Here's a tutorial from Kendo's docs: http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/asp-net-hello-services

Here's another example that deals with the Grid: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/tree/master/grid-webapi-crud

Comment: Do you have an example that shows how to do this using a ASP.NET Web API 2 server that returns JSON on REST calls? As to the "pretty much deprecated," the ASP.NET people I talk to at Microsoft all say to use Web API 2 for REST/JSON.

Comment: See the first link in my answer, it seems to be a pretty thorough example.

Comment: The grid-webapi-crud sample looks very useful except... it has no .js files. Where's the client half of it? Thanks.